# Cron task executed twice from Apache Tomcat in Windows Server 2012

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cron

I have a scheduled task defined in a Service

```
@Service 
public class SchedulerService {
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("syncWorker")
    private Worker worker;

@Scheduled(cron="0 */1 * * * ?")
    public void doScheduleEvolucionPartidas() {
        logger.debug("Start doScheduleEvolucionPartidas");      
        worker.workEvolucionPartidas();
        logger.debug("End doScheduleEvolucionPartidas");
    }

}
```

It should be exectuing once per minute, but I see in Tomcat log that it is being executed twice every minute.

Could you tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Could be 2 contexts initialized from ApplicationContext.xml & spring-servlet.xml

Comment: I think I know what the problem is: 
I have a Apache HTTPD 2.4 on port 80. When someonw type my IP I want apache to redirect to tomcat on port 8080. But hte problem came because I didnt want people accesing directly to apache welcome page, so I edited server.xml file adding the following:
<Context path="" docBase="tb">
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
</Context>
So I have my context as main on tomcat and when someone types my IP will go directly to my web app, but it makes that the cron jobs are executed twice

Comment: How could I fix that?